# Zend framework helper intellisense

Tags: zend-framework, intellisense, eclipse-pdt, helper

Not so much a programming problem, but more a productivity problem.
We've got quite a few custom view and action helpers in our project. Working with around 7 programmers.

Now when someone, creates a helper or if one would want to use a helper, it all goes through the brokers. This means we do not get intellisense for those helpers, which can be real time consuming, having to go look in the docs or the code files. This is ofcourse true for both build in and custom helpers.

Does any1 share this pain? Does any1 have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Eclipse with PDT but with Zend Studio you can do the following in a controller:

> `$this->_helper->`<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

and a box will appear with the default helpers. Same works for ViewHelpers when using it inside a View Script. The funny thing about this is, this will not work in the ZF perspective, but only from the PHP Perspective, which I think is using a customized PDT. So, yeah it's a bit odd.

Comment: This does idd work in pdt, but it just displays the properties of the helper broker, not any custom helper methods available in the project...

Comment: Might be a Zend Studio feature then. You can add the @method annotation to any magic methods to return possible methods though in some IDEs. See http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.method.pkg.html

Comment: Intellisense picks it up for me with PDT 2.2.  I have noticed that with 2.1 it wont recognize the @method or @property tags